# vimrc file, viminfo file

Tags: vim

I have a little bit convoluted question about location of vimrc file. I am using gvim/vim on windows. I tried to find the location of vimrc file. ":version" showed following data:
**user:   $HOME/_vimrc
system: $VIM/vimrc
$Home:  c:\users\xyz
$VIM:   c:\program files(x86)\vim**

I tried to search for "$HOME/_vimrc". I could not find it. So, I did :e $MYVIMRC and system "vimrc" poped up. Now I am wondering how come vim is taking "vimrc" from system folder and why there is no user "vimrc" file.

However, viminfo file is getting updated in the user folder.  "$HOME/_viminfo"

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The user .vimrc (or _vimrc, in your case) is not created by default in the $HOME directory. It is used as an override for the system vimrc configuration.

If you create that file, you can override the system vimrc profile.

Comment: u r rite. This makes sense. viminfo needs to be separate for every user. So, it gets created separately for every user. However, same vimrc is used as long as user does not want to create his own.